# Is a set contained in its Cartesian product with itself?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Given the Cartesian product $X = A \times A$, is $A \subset X$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An answer highly depends on the context and the meaning of the question.

The most probable one would be the context of axiomatic set theory, and the answer depends on your definition of an ordered pair, since, formally, $A\times A$ is the set of ordered pairs $(a_1, a_2)$ for all $a_1, a_2 \in A$. With [Kuratowski definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_pair#Kuratowski_definition) of ordered pair, the statement $\forall A: A \not\subset A\times A$ is related to [well-foundedness of set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity).

If some semantic context is the case and we think of sets as "types of objects", then $A\times A$ is the type of pairs, and we usually think that objects are not the same as pairs of objects, and the statement is clearly false.

If we consider "$A$ is a subset of $B$" as a somewhat broader notion, namely "$A$ can be embedded into $B$", then $A$ is definitelly a subset of $A\times A$ in a large number of ways: $x \mapsto (x,a)$ for a fixed $a\in A$, or $x \mapsto (a,x)$, or $x \mapsto (x,x)$, and, in general, many more.

I wish to emphasis that only the first answer makes sense if the question is about usual set theory, but I feel that thinking about it in some broader sense is quite useful.

Comment: The context I had in mind is mathematics, more precisely the construction of the different number sets. Since $\mathbb{N}$ contains no pairs, would you say that $\mathbb{N} \nsubseteq \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: @matteyas this still depends on the definition of $\mathbb{N}$ and the definition of a product and ordered pair. "Mathematics" is a too broad context, including algebra (where naturals are some free monoid) and axiomatic set theory (where naturals are, for example, $\{\varnothing, \{\varnothing\}, \{\varnothing, \{\varnothing\}\},\dots\}$.

Comment: What I had in mind was the Peano axioms, where 0 being a natural number is one of the axioms and all the other numbers are constructed through the successor function; no construction using empty sets is used here. Perhaps I should ask a new question, but what I'm interested in is how one shows that $\mathbb{N} \subset \mathbb{Z}$, where the integers are usually constructed by identifying ordered pairs in $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @matteyas Peano axioms define a theory of natural numbers, they do not mention sets. When you ask if $\mathbb{N} \subset \mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$ or if $\mathbb{N} \subset \mathbb{Z}$, you have to work inside another theory, set theory. Set theory itself has no notion of numbers. However, we can present a **model** of natural numbers inside set theory, providing a particular set $N$, a particular element $0 \in N$, a particular function $s:N\rightarrow N$ as a successor and prove that Peano axioms do hold here. So, naturals are not part of set theory; their **models** are.

Comment: @matteyas The usual construction of $\mathbb{Z}$ is as equivalence classes of pairs of naturals via $(a,b) \sim (c,d) \Leftrightarrow a+d=b+c$, and in this setting $\mathbb{N} \subset \mathbb{Z}$ in the last sense that I mentioned in the post through the embedding $n \mapsto [(n,0)]$.

Answer (score 4):

If $A=\emptyset$, then indeed $A\subset X$. Otherwise, there is *a copy of $A$* inside $X$ for every element of $A$, but the set $A$ itself is not necessarily exactly a subset of $X$. For every $a\in A$ we have $A\times\{a\}\subset X$ and $\{a\}\times A\subset X$. There is an obvious bijection between $A$ and $A\times\{a\}$.

A simple example for which it does not hold is $A=\{a\}$ with $a\neq\emptyset$. Then $X=\{(a,a)\}$ and $a\neq(a,a)$, so $A\not\subset X$.

Comment: Counterexample to the last statement: let $A = \{a, b, (a, b)\}$. Then $(a,b) \in A$ and $(a,b) \in A \times A$.

Comment: Oops, you're right… It should say that not every element in $A$ can be of the form $(a_1,a_2)$ with $a_1,a_2\in A$.

Comment: In particular if $A$ is nonempty, then it will contain an element with minimal rank, than this element cannot _also_ be a pair of other elements (at least assuming the usual Kuratowski definition).

Comment: On the other hand, with Quine-Rosser ordered pairs, it holds that $\varnothing=\langle\varnothing,\varnothing\rangle$, so with that definition $A=\{\varnothing\}$ would be another example of $A\subseteq A\times A$.

Answer (score -2):

Unfortunately its not.
Let $m \in A$. Then , $(m,m) \in A \times A=X$.
Now, What is the definition of $A \subset B$? --> Its $x \in A \Longrightarrow x \in B$.

Let your assumption $A \subset X$ is true, then $x \in A \Longrightarrow x \in X$
But we know $m \in A$ and $(m,m) \in X$. So this becomes $m \in A \Longrightarrow m \in X$. But we know $(m,m) \in X$ so this is clear contradiction. Hence your assumption is wrong. 
Here I don't used Quantifiers, because it needs a bit higher knowledge of logic, and you are saying I am not very good at set theory, so...

Comment: I don't quite see how you get to a contradiction though. If you take $A:=\{a,(a,a)\}$ and let $m=(a,a)$, then certainly $m\in A\implies m\in X$ holds for this particular $m$.

Comment: No, your question is because - I don't used quantifiers.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. You take $m$ arbitrarily, as to show that something holds for all $m$. I just gave a counter example for a specific $m$ that does not satisfy that property. Hence your proof is incorrect, as it does not hold for all $m$.

Comment: Let me think a bit

Comment: Yes you are right @Joffysloffy, because in some case $A \subset X$ (as you mentioned in your answer) happens. Oh, thanks to point the mistake.

Comment: You're welcome! By the way, your argument may also fail on sets for which $A\not\subset X$, but for which some elements of $A$ are also in $X$ (like the example I gave earlier).

Comment: Whatever it is, I was wrong... :p